# Grails (2.0.3) with rest plugin works! But unit test fails. Why?

Tags: rest, grails

Pardon if this is a n00b question, I'm a n00b to grails...

I have installed the "rest" plugin using `grails install-plugin rest`.

My service class has this code (redacted):

```
def index() {
  def data

  withRest(uri:'http://localhost:8090/some/valid/url/running/here/') {
    auth.basic 'admin', 'admin'
    def response = get(path: 'something', query: [format: 'json'])
    data = response.data
  }
  return data
}
```

If I run `grails console`, instantiate my service class and call `service.index()`, I get my expected JSON result. This code works as expected. It works through a controller. It even works through a controller via an integration test.

Here is my unit test:

```
void testIndex() {
    def response = service.index()
    assertEquals(response.total, 2)
    assertEquals(response.receipts.size, 2)
    assertEquals(response.receipts.collectEntries{ [it.id, [id: it.id]] }, [1: [id:1], 2:[id:2]])
}
```

This fails with an error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: torch.ReceiptService.withRest() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, torch.ReceiptService$_index_closure1) values: [[uri:http://localhost:8090/some/valid/url/running/here/], ...]
```

So it seems that when the test is running, the plugin is not active. I have not done any additional configuration regarding the plugin. I don't really understand why the test environment should have this class compiled differently.

My intention was to mock the network interface once I got this going, since it has an external dependency. But I'm taking it a step at a time.

Do I need to inject a mock `withRest()` to even run the test? Or is something else amiss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how unit tests work. No plugins are active, there's no Spring, Hibernate, etc. You're just running a class and so everything has to be mocked. Seems like REST is a poor candidate for mocking though, since then you'd just be testing the mocks.

I'd probably test it with a functional test. This is unfortunately less convenient than unit tests, but bad tests aren't very useful :) You could configure it so the url is looked up in the config to allow a different URL for testing so you don't need to hit an external service, and then setup a real REST service for testing that returns known values.

Comment: Thanks. This was only the beginning of my testing of it, but I got stalled right away. Seems like "unit" tests in grails are /very/ constrained. I may still end up using it here once the service does what it's supposed to eventually do (adapt the result of the rest call into a different format.)